# (When) can I assume boundary values in an LP relaxation are fixed in the MIP?

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, relaxations

Suppose I have an integer programming problem, specifically one with a set of binary decision variables $x_i \in \{0, 1\}$. So I'm trying to optimize a function $c=w \cdot x$ where $w$ is a vector of weights, subject to a set of constraints - mainly linear inequalities in $x$, i.e. $Mx \geq b$ for some matrix $M$ and vector $b$.

So I decide to try linear relaxation, i.e. I solve the same problem but where $x$ can take fractional values between 0 and 1. Now let's say that some, but not all, of the $x_i$ in the optimal solution are on the boundary, meaning that they wound up being either 0 or 1 exactly.

Can I then assume that in the solution to the original IP those same $x_i$ will still be those values? Does it depend on what kind of constraints I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.  For example, consider the problem

$$ \eqalign{\text{maximize } & y\cr
\text{subject to } & - 2 x + y \le 0\cr
                   & 2 x + y \le 2\cr
x, y \in \{0,1\}& \cr}$$

The linear relaxation has optimal solution $x = 1/2, y=1$.  But there is no
integer programming solution with $y=1$: 
the optimal solutions of the integer programming problem are $(x,y) = (0,0)$ and $(1,0)$.

Comment: So simple and so obvious. Are there, then, conditions in which I might be able to assume as such?

Comment: No nontrivial conditions that I know.  You can, of course, try the integer programming problem fixing the variables that have values $0$ or $1$ in the solution of your relaxation.  If the objective coefficients are integers and the optimal objective value of this new problem is the floor (for a maximization problem) or ceiling (for a minimization) of the optimal objective value of the relaxation, then this must be optimal.